# How to arrange button on each side of a horizontal stack view

Tags: ios, uistackview

Here is a print screen of my arrangement:

[image]

I want my Info button to sit on the left part of the stack view like the Add button is sitting. How can I do that ?
I want space between buttons, but using Spacing property of the Stack View will not behave correctly if I run on different iPhone dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage this in the Interface Builder. Select your horizontal stack view and set **Alignment** to *Fill* and **Distribution** to *Equal Spacing*. Leave **Spacing** to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You Can't. The purpose of the UIStackView is to stack views. You can add significant space between them but you can't really calculate that for different size classes.

I would love it if Apple made Flexible Space Items available to UIStackView

Comment: I think you can be selection Equal Spacing for the Distribution property

Comment: This is incorrect, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can achieve this easily without using `UIToolBar` and `Flexible Space Items`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039893/751641) is correct. I just want to add some code.

Programmatically in `Swift 5`:

```
private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 0

    return stackView
}()
```

Somewhere you add arranged subviews:

```
func setupUI() {
    addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(deleteButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(shareButton)
}
```

`stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing` is a key here

`stackView.alignment = .fill` is not that important (it's about placement in vertical axis - perpendicular to UIStackView's axis)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the alignment of StackView to **Trailing**